# Migrating the UI CSS in angular application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tailwind-css, bootstrap-5

I want to upgrade my UI css ,
I have two option migrate my bootstrap from 3.4.1 to latest version, or use Tailwind css
Which is better approach? please help.

I read the documentation of latest Bootstrap version, there are lot of breaking changes
So I have doubt whether it will be time consuming to migrate it.